# Python: Unicode output to csv using unicodecsv

Tags: python, json, csv, unicode

I writing some unicode output to csv using the unicodecsv module.  Everything is working as expected, but I'm trying to build it out by adding some headers or field names.  So far, I've tried a number of different ways, but I can't come up with how to add the field names.

I've tried other unicode solutions and this module seems to be the most elegant to implement so I'm trying to use it if possible.  If there are other suggestions, I'm up for them.  Any ideas?? Please see relevant code below.

```
import unicodecsv

with open('c:\pull.csv', 'wb+') as f:
            csv_writer = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
            for i in changes['user']['login'], changes['title'], str(changes['changed_files']), str(changes['commits']) :
                csv_writer.writerow([changes['user']['login'], changes['title'],changes['changed_files'], changes['commits']])
```

Sample output for changes in the csv file:

`'John Doe', 'Some Title', 1, 1`

Comment: Can you edit the question to give a small example for `changes`. Also what headers do you want to add?

Comment: @MartinEvans I adjusted the example with sample output.  I would like for the headers to be Name, Title, Changed Files, Commits.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Could you though add some sample input for what `changes` would containe?

Comment: @MartinEvans The output is the json returned by querying GitHub for getting a single pull request.  Please see here: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the json data you have, there is only one user entry, so the following should work:

```
with open('c:\pull.csv', 'wb+') as f:
    csv_writer = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')

    # Write a header row (do once)
    # csv_writer.writerow(["login", "title", "changed_files", "commits"])

    # Write data row
    csv_writer.writerow([changes['user']['login'], changes['title'],changes['changed_files'], changes['commits']])
```

If you want a header row, uncomment the line. This would then give you an output file:

```
login,title,changed_files,commits
octocat,new-feature,5,3
```

Comment: @MartinEvans...That worked like a charm (knocking myself in the head, because I should have thought to try that).  Thanks!!